# Pique, peek, and peak vs. per se, persay, and per say

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Compare the question "[What does persay mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57517/what-does-persay-mean)" with "[Is it peek, peak, or pique?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101450/is-it-peek-peak-or-pique)". Both of them are about common errors and while the former is not as well-formulated as the latter, it has nevertheless been closed while the latter has not. That said, I dare say that *persay* for *per se* is at least as common as *peak* for *pique* and this is evident from the fact that its question has received ~4000 views in 11 months. That does not sound "too localised" to me.

So, should the *persay* question have been closed? Or should the *pique* question be closed? Considering the number of views it has garnered, should the *persay* question be reopened and perhaps cleaned up?

Comment: But it's simply *not true* that "persay" is about as common an error as "peak". In [NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=per+se%2Cpersay&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=), it flatlines against "per se", and it only gets 423K hits on Google Internet compared to 33,600K for the "correct" version. Which isn't even English anyway, so it's not surprising some people don't spell it right. I accidentally closevated *peak/pique* because I didn't realise how common it is, but that doesn't apply at all with *persay/per se*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You might also want to google "per say" and note the existence of dictionary definitions for it as a frequent misspelling. The question is about, as Stoney puts it, ear-errors, which makes the spelling provided by the questioner, flexible. Also, and FWIW, I encounter "per say" with a degree of annoying frequency.

Comment: Okay, so I Googled ["per say"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22per+say%22&oq=%22per+say%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j61l2.3394&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) just like you said. As you'll see, the first result is Wikipedia saying *Per se may refer to: Per se, a Latin phrase meaning "in itself".* right there on the Google homepage "snippet view". How does that support your case for ELU needing to keep a question about it open for more people to find "interesting" things to say about it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're being difficult as usual :) What do the other results on that page say? Please pay close attention to the ones that include the word _dictionary_ in them.

Comment: I'm really not trying to be "difficult". The very first Google result for *per say* explains it without even needing to follow the link. It makes no difference what any *other* links might say if you've already got everything you need to know (including Google apparently "translating" your misspelling so as to put the *right* page at the top of the results list).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Google is not a reference. I'm refuting your contention that "per say" is not a common misspelling of "per se" or a common misspelling per se. It is _so_ common that its commonness warrants entries in dictionaries and eggcorn databases. It also registers 2.1M hits. This also makes the question anything but "too localised".

Comment: I sense this is going nowhere. I use Google to find things. The first thing it found was a Wikipedia article saying exactly what you'd need to know if you were wondering what *per say* means. But assuming you *were* wondering, what useful extra information would you be getting (or indeed, *seeking*) if you decided Wikipedia wasn't a reliable reference, so you clicked on a link to the ELU question? And why does that question need to be reopened to add some more (imho, pointless) discussion?

Comment: You are again simply being evasive. You contend that a) the issue is "too localised", and b) the misspelling is uncommon. (I grant you that you were talking about "persay" rather than "per say".) I have just demonstrated that both these contentions are false. Furthermore, the view count demonstrates the usefulness of the question to the faceless hoi polloi out there. That should be sufficient for you to consider reopening and reassessing the question. You're welcome to try to close it again as "General Reference" as you might then want to do with the "Peak/pique" question if you so desire.

Comment: I can only closevote once on a question, and I did that 20 minutes after *per say* was asked a year ago, so it's out of my hands now. Whatever - neither of us seems to have a "killer argument" that will convince the other, and the question *has* been reopened. As explained, I wouldn't want *peak/pique* closed because it seems inherently interesting as a (to me, unexpectedly prevalent) "eggcorn". About the only "improvement" I can see for *peak/pique* is that I'd have defined it with the equally common *"in **and of** itself"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think both questions would have a happy home on ELL.  But since I can't move to migrate them to there, I instead err on the side of 'openness' and vote to reopen persay rather than close pique.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the *persay* question was probably closed because the title represents an ordinary mis-spelling, much as we close questions which turn on typographical errors.

And I'd guess that most of the views of that question arose because people looked at it and said "persay? I've never heard of persay. What *does* it mean?" - and then were disappointed to find it was common-or-garden-variety *per se*.

If I'd been around at the time I would probably have voted against closing, because the question isn't in fact about a mis-spelling but about a term which OP heard and didn't know how to look up (which I imagine is the source of almost all instances of this error). Once you get past that, however, it's an ordinary dictionary question. Correct the error, and there's no question left.

The *peek* question, on the other hand, was about a very similar widespread ear-error which involves redefining the underlying semantics of the phrase. It's an eggcorn, or very nearly so, which does not resolve to a dictionary question, because it never occurs to users that it has to be looked up. It's an error that has to be explained.

Comment: I don't think that the majority of the 4000 views are from ELU users. Most of them have very likely been referred to by Google searches for [per say or persay](https://www.google.com/search?q=per+say), the results of which prominently include the ELU question page. If this is the case, then it isn't really _too localised_ at all. As for eggcorns/ear-errors, it could perhaps be argued that _per say_ could also redefine underlying semantics and require an explanation as provided.

Comment: @coleopterist  Agreed. I'm just guessing about why one was closed and the other wasn't. As for opening *persay*, the answer there looks conclusive, so I don't see any particular reason for reopening. But if you have something to add, I'll be happy to vote for reopening.

Comment: I don't particularly have anything to add except perhaps linking to a dictionary definition. However, I think that it matters whether a question is _closed_ or _open_. Closed questions are liable to be deleted at any time. Moreover, questions closed for being too localised (which this isn't) are prime candidates for deletion. I also believe that a closed question taints its answers with its blue and bold banner of unreliability :|

Comment: @coleopterist: I don't share your perception of what it means to be *closed* in this case. No-one is likely to vote for deleting it, and even if they *did* (and if it wasn't a mod, if they got enough others to vote likewise), others would undelete it. There's nothing to add about a simple misspelling that's almost unknown in print, and occurs in only 1% of all casual references (and doubtless, some facetious) on the Internet at large.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That [might change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122451/176533). :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Regardless of whether that change goes through (or *has gone through*, for all I know), it won't affect the situation as regards the specific question we're discussing here. It was fully and completely answered within 4 minutes of being asked.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It hasn't. If it had, you'd see **status-completed**. By the way, I was just addressing the point of self-deletion.

Comment: @Alenanno: I think we're at cross purposes here. I'm talking about the question on main which we're discussing here. You seem to be talking about *this question on meta*. I've downvoted *this* question because I disagree with coleopterist's position, but I certainly wouldn't vote to *close* it. In fact, it's quite unusual for anyone to closevote on meta (I expect the mods just unilaterally delete anything manifestly unsuitable).